# Facebook post live preview not showing when shared in Buddypress website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, buddypress

I am working on this community website https://www.doggowuf.com/ build on WordPress with Buddypress and Youzify plugins.

When I share links of other websites it pulls the preview (featured image) of the web page but when I share any Facebook post on the website it does not do the same.

Is it some kind of restriction from Facebook or it is flaw from my end?

[Image : Facebook post preview not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArSST.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate facebook with your website first

please Refer to
https://wordpress.com/support/facebook-integration/#publicize-to-facebook